# holomorphic line bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, holomorphic-bundles

Consider the unit disk $\mathbb D \subset \mathbb R^2$, and a holomorphic map $f :\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$. $df$ can be thought of as $df: T^{0,1}D \to f^*(T^{0,1}D)$(the pull back), that is, an element in $L(TD, T^{\ast}D)$ which is isomorphic to $T^{\ast} D \otimes f^{\ast}TD$. Then $df = f' dz \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial w}$ in basis.

I was told that there is a "connection" $\nabla$ on $T^{\ast}D \otimes f^{\ast}D$, which is compatible with the hyperbolic metric, and I need to compute $\nabla f'dz \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial w}$. This boils down to computing $\nabla dz \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial w}$.

My guess here is that we are viewing $T^{\ast} D \otimes f^{\ast}D$ as a complex vector bundle, then we can define some sort of complex connection on it that will be compatible with the hyperbolic metric on the unit disk. How to define such a connection and what is the compatibility condition?

Update: Let $E$ be a holomorphic line bundle. Then an hermitian structure $H$ on $E$ is given by a positive real function and the Chern connection $E$ is locally given as $\nabla = d + \partial log H$.

How can I use this statement to compute $\nabla dz \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial w}.

My interpretation is that $\nabla dz \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial w} = \nabla dz \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial w} + dz \otimes \nabla \frac{\partial}{\partial w} = \partial log H \otimes \partial w + dz \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial w}$, what is $d\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\bar{\partial}f$ rather than $df$...? In any case, a differential $df(z)$ is usually viewed as mapping $T_{z}D$ to $T_{f(z)}D$; that is, $df$ may be viewed as a section of the bundle whose fibre at $z$ is $\operatorname{Hom}(T_{z}D, T_{f(z)}D)$, a.k.a., $\operatorname{Hom}(TD, f^{*}TD)$.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know.  If $f$ is holomorphic, shouldn't $\bar \partial f$ just be zero? I was just told that to express $df$ in basis, it should be of the form $df = f' d \eta \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, that is just so confusing.

Comment: I see, maybe it should be $\nabla df $ can be expressed in terms of $d \eta \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

Comment: Is there any account of connection in the complex situation?

Comment: Just a quick note: You're right that $\bar{\partial}f = 0$ if $f$ is holomorphic. Generally, $\bar{\partial}$ acts like exterior differentiation in a holomorphic vector bundle because "the transition functions are $\bar{\partial}$-constant". In case it's helpful, in the presence of an Hermitian metric, there's a unique [Chern connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_connection) compatible with the metric (analogously to the Levi-Civita connection in Riemannian geometry) and whose $(0, 1)$-component is $\bar{\partial}$.

Comment: So Chern connection is some sort of connection for complex manifolds I assume? I want to learn how to compute $\nabla df$ especially for the hyperbolic metric of the poincare disk, is there any reference for that one?